# Weird behavior with single and double quoted strings

Tags: php

So, why in PHP, does the following code, print 'false'.

```
var_export('\'' === "\'");
```

Isn't it exactly the same?

Comment: If you `var_dump('\'');` you get `"'"`, with `var_dump("\'");` you get `"\'"`

Comment: @NigelRen Very weird hmm.

Comment: No these are not same, if you do `var_export("\'");` with double quotes, this will return `'\\\''` but if you do with single quotes this outputs `'\''` with single quotes.

Comment: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: @emppeak I guess this has to do with how escaping might be slightly different for quoted / double quoted strings. Kinda weird if you ask me.